# Using both look_at and flip_h in Godot

Tags: rotation, godot, angles

I am trying to have a player running in a side scroller platformer with its arms independent from its body, so that the arms can follow the mouse (to aim).

The issue is that when the character goes to the left I use `flip_h` to flim it and its arm, which makes `look_at()` obviously not work properly. But I'm not sure how to go about fixing it since we can't just invert the rotation angle of the arm because its values do not make sense to me (they are incremented very slowly and are not comprised between 0 and 360).

[GitHub project to demonstrate the issue](https://github.com/Balatzar/Test-Rotate-Flip)

Player script

```
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

@onready var animator = get_node("AnimatedSprite2D")
@onready var arm = get_node("Arm")


func _ready():
    animator.play("Run")

func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    # Handle Jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction == 1:
        animator.flip_h = false
        arm.flip_h = false
    elif direction == -1:
        animator.flip_h = true
        arm.flip_h = true
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

Arm script

```
extends Sprite2D


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    print(rotation)
    print(flip_h)
    # rotation = get_global_mouse_position().angle_to_point(position)
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    look_at(mouse_pos)
```

Comment: `they are incremented very slowly and are not comprised between 0 and 360` Its probably a value in radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flip_h` is making your arm point in the "opposite" direction when you use `look_at`.  A quick, simple solution would be to look at the "opposite" point when facing left, that is, `look_at` the mouse location flipped across your character:

```
func _process(delta):
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    if flip_h:
        mouse_pos = Vector2(global_position + (global_position - mouse_pos))
    look_at(mouse_pos)
```

[image: The character, the mouse, and where the code should look instead]

Comment: Well done! Thanks a lot :)